# ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance is creating non-empty generic collections .Net 8

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, .net-8.0

In .NET 8, when using `ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance` or `ActivatorUtilities.GetServiceOrCreateInstance` to initalize generic collections, some of them are initlized with elements.

Example:

```
public interface ITest { }

public class Test : ITest { }

public class Test2 : ITest { }

public static void Main(string[] args)
{

    var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();

    serviceCollection.AddTransient<ITest, Test>();
    serviceCollection.AddTransient<ITest, Test2>();

    var services = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();

    var collection = ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<ObservableCollection<ITest>>(services);
}
```

In .NET 6, that code would create an empty instance of `ObservableCollection<ITest>`.

In .NET 8, the `collection` object is an instance of `ObservableCollection<ITest>` with two elements (an instance of `Test` and another of `Test2`).
`ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance` is now choosing the constructor public `ObservableCollection(IEnumerable<T> collection);` due to this change: https://github.com/dotnet/docs/issues/31785.
As it chooses the constructor requesting `IEnumerable<T>`, the collection receives as argument an instance of each registration of `ITest` in the dependency injection container.

Note that this happens on any .NET collection that has a constructor with the parameter `IEnumerable<T>`.

My problem is that:

- I'm using `ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance` on a custom JSON deserializer.
- The type being deserialized may be any of the types used on our APIs.
- In some APIs we use .NET collections and due to the described issue, we are getting deserialized collections with more elements than the ones in the JSON.

Any workaround to solve this issue is highly appreciated. I need to be able to create **empty** instances of the .Net collections (as in .NET 6) using `ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance` or `ActivatorUtilities.GetServiceOrCreateInstance` or another alternative that would work for any class/interface used in my application.

I've already open this issue: https://github.com/dotnet/docs/issues/39216.

Comment: Probably there is no reason to open the issue since this seems to be intended behavior as basically the provided github page explains the source of the issue.